# Change relative position of a dragged element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery UI in order to drag some icons. I succeeded using draggable function.

But now, when I drag the icons with my finger (it's on phone) I wanted to see the icon being dragged so I decided to increase the width (because we have big fingers).

However, when I drag the icon this happens:

[image: illustrated problem]

Also for information, here is my code for dragging event:

```js
$("#icon").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).css('width', "150%");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).css('width', "100%");
  }
});
```

Comment: if you need something else to understand, let me know ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draggable has a [`cursorAt`](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursorAt) option:

> Sets the offset of the dragging helper relative to the mouse cursor. Coordinates can be given as a hash using a combination of one or two keys: `{ top, left, right, bottom }`.

Which you can use like:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  cursorAt: { left: 5 }
});
```

jQuery UI doesn't support touch events by default. I believe you're using it with jQuery UI Touch Punch. Hope it works.

Comment: Well I added a code which adapts JQuery UI for touch events, i am going to test your solution soon. Thanks :)

Comment: @guillaumekotarba In case you haven't checked http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Ok i will have a look at it :)